# SPServices Set PeoplePicker field in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, spservices, people-picker

I've seen a LOT of posts about this, and I am sorry to add to them, but I have spent a lot of time going through them and cannot find an answer that is working in my case.

My objective is to populate a PeoplePicker field with the current user via jQuery/JavaScript and SPServices, if possible.

My first and most obvious attempt was to use the SPServices function `$().SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker({ ... });`, however, this function does not seem to be working or I am not understanding how it is *supposed* to work.

Here is my attempt:

```
var currUser = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({ fieldName: "Name" }).split('|')[1];
$().SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker({
  peoplePickerDisplayName: "Assigned To",
  valueToSet: currUser,
  checkNames: true
});
```

The above code is not working for me. I have confirmed that the `SPFindPeoplePicker` function **is** selecting the correct PeoplePicker field by posting the response to the console, but the `valueToSet` parameter is being ignored. I've tried passing it a user title, and hard coding a specific user to ensure there is not an issue with the `currUser` variable.

Could somebody explain what is going wrong with this function? Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to function?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you are doing nothing wrong, the rendering of people picker has changed in SharePoint 2013. So I use this walkaround, I hope it helps you [link](http://sympmarc.com/2012/04/22/working-with-sharepoint-people-pickers-with-jquery-a-new-function-called-findpeoplepicker)

Comment: Hi @Marco , Thank you for your response. I was guessing that might be the case, but couldn't find it confirmed in my research. However, I don't see a workaround on the link you provided. It appears to be a clone of the existing `().SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker` function. I'm basically getting the exactly the same response.

Comment: what is "Assigned To" here?. ID of `PeoplePicker` control?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using SharePoint 2013 I would recommend you to consider a different approach, in SharePoint 2013 was introduced a so called `Client Rendering Mode (CSR)` which is intended for rendering of List Views and Forms using HTML and JavaScript.  To get acquainted with CSR follow these articles:

- [INTRODUCTION TO CLIENT-SIDE RENDERING IN SHAREPOINT 2013](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/04/14/introduction-to-client-side-rendering-in-sharepoint-2013/)
- [SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

### How to initialize User field in New/Edit forms using CSR

Below example demonstrates how to populate User field (AssignedTo) in New form for a List (Tasks list)

Template code:

```
   (function () {
    var ctx = {};
    ctx.Templates = {};
    ctx.Templates.Fields = {
        'AssignedTo': {
            'NewForm': renderAssignedTo
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);
})();

function renderAssignedTo(ctx) {
     //get current user properties
     var displayName = $('div#SuiteNavUserName').text();
     var loginName = String.format('i:0#.f|membership|{0}',_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName);
     var currentUserEntry = createUserEntity(loginName,displayName);
     //Set user default value
     ctx.CurrentFieldValue = [];   //Note: it is assumed the user field is a multi-valued field (!)
     ctx.CurrentFieldValue.push(currentUserEntry);  
     return SPClientPeoplePickerCSRTemplate(ctx);
}

function createUserEntity(userLoginName,userDisplayName)
{
   return {
      Description: userLoginName,
      DisplayText: userDisplayName,
      EntityGroupName: "",
      EntityType: "",
      HierarchyIdentifier: null,
      IsResolved: true,
      Key: userLoginName,
      MultipleMatches: [],
      ProviderDisplayName: "",
      ProviderName: ""
   };
}
```

### How to apply the changes

There are at least two options how to apply the changes:

1. Using [JSLink property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.basexsltlistwebpart.jslink.aspx)
2. Place JavaScript template on page via `Script Editor`/`Content Editor`
   web parts

Here is how to apply the changes using the **second option**:

1. Switch the page (`NewForm.aspx`) into edit mode
2. Add `Script Editor` webpart right below the list view web part.
3. Put the specified code by wrapping it using `script` tag code into the Script Editor, for example: `<script type="text/javascript">{Template JS code goes here}</script>`
4. Save the page

### Results

[image]

Comment: 40 lines of code to add a string to one field. thanks, microsoft

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment to my question, the `SPFindPeoplePicker` function currently does not work for SharePoint 2013. However, I was able to find an alternative solution and posted it on my other question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123535/sp2013-trigger-people-picker-validation).

Comment: Please add code snippets from the referred blog

Comment: Your link worked for me. calling AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor on the peoplepicker instance did the trick.